# Load only certain part of a page using ajax and the remaining part containing the form shouldnot reload

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a controller which shows all the orders.It has a form which will take the search filters and print the filtered results accordingly.Filters work for the first page but on going to the second page the search filter form is reset and it shows all the orders without any search filter.My idea is when the next page is opened only the table has to load and search filters have to remain the same.It can be done through ajax request but don't know how.Please help thanks in advance

Comment: It should be only the filter parameter that needed to pass through when going to other pages?

Comment: yes that would be enough i guess